# Avoid glitch in a FF circuit

Tags: digital-logic, fpga, flipflop, logic-gates

In the following circuit implemented in an FPGA I have a glitch on the OUT1 (due, I guess, to the propagation delay of the upper XOR which causes to have on the lower XOR two input not syncronized).
[image]
Here can be seen the waveform simulation. My question is : how to remove the glitch maintaining the same output values?
I think I have to avoid the direct path between the two XOR ports by using some FF but I do not know how precisely.

[image]

Comment: Put the XOR gate into a DFF clocked by CLK. You'll have a 1-CLK delay in that path then, naturally. Incidentally, if IN is an asynchronous input from a pin, or comes from another clock domain, add an extra DFF between IN and your first DFF, for protection against metastability.

Comment: You mean at the output of the upper xor?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First rule of FPGAs: If your output cannot tolerate glitches, never, ever drive the output directly from combinatorial logic. Always use synchronous signals - that is, direct from a flip-flop. The problem is that the logic input signals are not guaranteed to have equal propagation delays from the sources, due to different routing paths.

So take your glitchy XOR output and run it through a D FF, just like Tony M suggests. For safety's sake, do it for both of them.